# Private mode - meta data

Tags: html, meta-tags

I need to create a small website with a "private posts mode" like Posterous did: http://blog.posterous.com/new-private-posts-on-posterous

Do I need to specify some special meta data that prevents the pages from indexing by search engines like Google?

I want to keep it as private as possible.

Comment: You can create a robot.txt file and put it in the root. Have a look at this short guide http://www.seoconsultants.com/robots-text-file/ .. look for disallow. So your page will not have login, only secrect paths?

Comment: Yes, it's only a secret path. I think the robots.txt would be a problem because everyone would find all the "secret" links inside by taking a look at example.com/robots.txt, right?.

Comment: Well basically you will only allow engines to your ‘promotional’ content of your site (if any). Otherwise you will not have any links linking to ‘secret content’. It is not accessible to search engines. So if disallow everything by default and then allow the ‘promotional’ content you should be fine.

Comment: Besides (depending on your hash) it is unlikely that someone will stumble upon a secret URL. Also you could monitor that none is visiting your site in a systematic way. If they do, and you don’t - you could ensure that no matter the URL something resembling content is returned.

Comment: robots.txt would be ill advised if you want to keep the link safe from random people. but the robots meta tag has the exact same effect and can be placed on the relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you're creating something like the [unlisted function in youtube](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181547) where a video is only available to the people that got a direct link to it?

In that case you might want to add a robots meta tag on your page, setting it to NOINDEX,FOLLOW.

It is placed inside the `<head>` portion of your page and can look something like this to prevent indexing but allow following of links on the page.

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

More information on this can be found here:

http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

To make it 100% private however you will need to implement a login system so that only people who were allowed (say, facebook style wall posts) or have the key (protected zip archives style) can see the content.